# doubly linked list in C sorting problems

Tags: c

I am trying to write a method that sorts the elements in a doubly linked list. The list is made up of structs with a forward and backward pointer (flink, blink) to the next element. head->blink should be null, tail->flink should be null (aka not circular). I tried a selection sort approach but I keep getting a segmentation fault. I have isolated the problem into the commented lines. However I included all of my code, the sort method is at the bottom.

```
//header (dblLinkList.h)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _DblLinkList {
    struct _DblLinkList *flink;
    struct _DblLinkList *blink;
    int num;
} DblLinkList;

struct _DblLinkList *head, *tail;

struct _DblLinkList *init(int nElements);
void sort(struct _DblLinkList *listNode);
void print(struct _DblLinkList *listNode);

//implementation

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dblLinkList.h"

int main() {
    struct _DblLinkList *list1 = init(2);
    printf("-----Head to Tail------\n");
    print(list1);
    printf("Sorting...\n");
    sort(list1);
    printf("-----Head to Tail------\n");
    print(list1);
}

struct _DblLinkList *init(int nElements) {
    struct _DblLinkList *listNode;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
        listNode = (struct _DblLinkList *)malloc(sizeof(struct _DblLinkList));
        listNode->num = random();

        if(head == NULL) {
            head = listNode;
            listNode->blink = NULL;
        } else {
            tail->flink = listNode;
            listNode->blink = tail;
        }
        tail = listNode;
        listNode->flink = NULL;
    }
    return listNode;
}

void print(struct _DblLinkList *listNode) {
    for(listNode = head; listNode != NULL; listNode = listNode->flink) {
        printf("%d\n", listNode->num);
    }
}

void sort(struct _DblLinkList *listNode) {
    //Not working properly
    struct _DblLinkList *listNode2;
    struct _DblLinkList *minNode;
    struct _DblLinkList *temp = (struct _DblLinkList *)malloc(sizeof(struct _DblLinkList));

    //start from the head and traverse the list
    for(listNode = head; listNode != NULL; listNode = listNode->flink) {
        minNode = listNode;
        listNode2 = listNode->flink;
        for(;listNode2 != NULL;  listNode2 = listNode2->flink) {
            if (listNode2->num < minNode->num) {
                minNode = listNode2;
            }
        }
//Problem Lies here vvvvvvvvvvvv
            temp->flink = listNode->flink;
            temp->blink = listNode->blink;  
            listNode->blink = listNode2;
            listNode->flink = listNode2->flink;
            listNode2->flink = temp;
            listNode2->blink = temp->blink; 
        printf("min: %d\n", minNode->num);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You tagged this C and C++...it looks like C to me, though. Which is it, just to be explicitly clear?

Comment: If you run your program in a debugger, you should be to identify *exactly* which line triggered the seg-fault.  You should then be able to inspect the variable values at that point, and compare them to what you expect them to be.

Comment: Agreed, this looks like compilable C.

Comment: @Matt : Will you accept an answer to this question that uses C++ code?

Comment: Is this some zany professor's homework or is there a specific reason you are sorting a dlinked list? Can you not read it into another structure, sort it, and read it back?

Comment: @ildjarn no

@gecko I cannot read it into another structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(;listNode2 != NULL;  listNode2 = listNode2->flink)
```

This loop **only exits when listNode2 is `NULL`**. So we've established that at this point `listNode2 == NULL`.

> Thou shalt not follow the NULL
>   pointer, for chaos and madness await
>   thee at its end.

And here is what you're doing, breaking the second commandment

```
listNode2->flink = temp;
```

Comment: @Arthur Shipkowski Good call; found another one :))

Comment: Heh, and here I deleted my comment, figuring you'd just had a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `listNode2` can be `NULL` after that `for` loop. You should check that before you try to access `listNode2->flink`.

Comment: Not the only problem with the routine, but it looks like the source of the segfault to me.

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few problems in the code:

1. You keep inserting the same chunk of memory, `temp` when you are moving nodes around.
2. When you are moving `listnode` away, `listnode->flink->blink` (before the move) still points to `listnode`.
3. Same as #2, but for `listnode->blink->flink`
4. When you move listnode, you potentially skip all the nodes between old position and `listnode2`, as `linstnode->flink` is now `listnode2->flink`, which is not necessarily the old value. This won't cause a crash, but it will leave some nodes unsorted.
5. When moving nodes around, I didn't see any special handling of `head` an `tail`, so they will probably point to weird nodes when you are done. One trick to handle this seamlessly is to make them into concrete `_DblLinkList` structures, so that the code is not riddled with `if` statements.

There may be other problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
FTFY: still pretty ugly hack but should work

--- 2.c 2011-06-07 13:03:48.000000000 -0700
+++ 1.c 2011-06-07 13:49:18.000000000 -0700
@@ -7,7 +7,8 @@
     int num;
 } DblLinkList;

-struct _DblLinkList *head, *tail;
+struct _DblLinkList *head = NULL;
+struct _DblLinkList *tail = NULL;

 struct _DblLinkList *init(int nElements);
 void sort(struct _DblLinkList *listNode);
@@ -35,16 +36,16 @@
     for(i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
         listNode = (struct _DblLinkList *)malloc(sizeof(struct _DblLinkList));
         listNode->num = random();
+               listNode->flink = NULL;
+               listNode->blink = NULL;

         if(head == NULL) {
             head = listNode;
-            listNode->blink = NULL;
         } else {
             tail->flink = listNode;
             listNode->blink = tail;
         }
         tail = listNode;
-        listNode->flink = NULL;
     }
     return listNode;
 }
@@ -55,29 +56,33 @@
     }
 }

-void sort(struct _DblLinkList *listNode) {
+void sort(struct _DblLinkList *_listNode) {
     //Not working properly
-    struct _DblLinkList *listNode2;
-    struct _DblLinkList *minNode;
-    struct _DblLinkList *temp = (struct _DblLinkList *)malloc(sizeof(struct _DblLinkList));
+       struct _DblLinkList* listNode = head;
+    struct _DblLinkList *listNode2 = NULL;
+    struct _DblLinkList *minNode = head;
+    struct _DblLinkList *temp = NULL;

     //start from the head and traverse the list
-    for(listNode = head; listNode != NULL; listNode = listNode->flink) {
-        minNode = listNode;
+    for(; listNode != NULL; listNode = listNode->flink) {
         listNode2 = listNode->flink;
         for(;listNode2 != NULL;  listNode2 = listNode2->flink) {
             if (listNode2->num < minNode->num) {
                 minNode = listNode2;
             }
-        }
-//Problem Lies here vvvvvvvvvvvv
-            temp->flink = listNode->flink;
-            temp->blink = listNode->blink;
-            listNode->blink = listNode2;
-            listNode->flink = listNode2->flink;
-            listNode2->flink = temp;
-            listNode2->blink = temp->blink;
+                       if (listNode->num > listNode2->num) {
+                               temp = listNode;
+                               listNode = listNode2;
+                               temp->flink = listNode2->flink;
+                               listNode->flink = temp;
+                               listNode->blink = temp->blink;
+                               listNode2 = temp;
+                               listNode2->blink = listNode;
+                               if (head == listNode2)
+                                       head = listNode;
+                       }
         printf("min: %d\n", minNode->num);
         }
     }
+}
```

Comment: yes! thank you. I knew I was on the right track I just couldnt figure out the order of changing the pointers

Comment: I should say, its in order but not all the nodes are not there after the sort.